# How to give blank value to integer field in temp table?

Tags: openedge, progress-4gl

I have written a simple query but want to show blank value to integer field in temp table. As you know if there is no data in integer field then 0 is the default value but our client says it should be blank instead of default value 0.

```
DEFINE TEMP-TABLE tt_data
       FIELD CarColour AS CHARACTER
       FIELD Qty  AS INTEGER.

FOR EACH <db> NO-LOCK WHERE <db.field> = "White Car" AND <db.field> = "Red Car":
         DISPLAY <db.field1> <db.field2>.
END.

/* Note  <db.field1> is CHARACTER  <db.field2> is INTEGER */

/* DISPLAYED VALUE IS */

WHITE    0  /* There is no qty for this white car so its showing default value 0 */

RED     100
```

So when I store these data to temp table White car QTY should be blank instead of 0.

Note - I cannot change Temp-Table Field Type.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This may get you what you need. Using the unknown value is the closest thing to NULL in progress.

```
DEFINE TEMP-TABLE tt_data
   FIELD CarColour AS CHARACTER
   FIELD Qty       AS INTEGER   init ?.
```

Answer (score 5):

Use the FORMAT option on those fields.

```
DISPLAY 0 FORMAT ">>>,>>>" SKIP 
        1 FORMAT ">>>,>>>" SKIP
```